# Форма обратной связи не работает

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, ajax

Помогите запустить форму

```
<!--form-->
    <form id="application" action=" application.php" method="POST" name="application">
       <a href="application" class="h1">
        <h1>Форма заказа</h1>
      </a>
         <input name="name" id="applicationName" maxlength="100" placeholder="Введите ваше имя" required />
         <input name="email" type="email" id="applicationEmail" maxlength="100" placeholder="Введите ваш E-mail" required />
         <input name="telephone" type="Tel" id="applicationTelephone" maxlength="20" placeholder="Введите ваш телефон" required />
         <input name="message" type="text" id="applicationMessage" maxlength="500" placeholder="Сообщение" required/>
         <button class="applicationButton" type="submit" form="application">Отправить</button>
      </form>



<?php 

$sendto   = "bushido-market@ukr.net"; // почта, на которую будет приходить письмо
$username = $_POST['name'];   // сохраняем в переменную данные полученные из поля c именем
$usertel = $_POST['telephone']; // сохраняем в переменную данные полученные из поля c телефонным номером
$usermail = $_POST['email']; // сохраняем в переменную данные полученные из поля c адресом электронной почты
$usermessage = $_POST['message']; // сохраняем в переменную данные полученные из поля c адресом электронной почты

// Формирование заголовка письма
$subject  = "Новое сообщение";
$headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";

// Формирование тела письма
$msg  = "<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'>";
$msg .= "<h2 style='font-weвведите сюда кодight:bold;border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;'>Cообщение с сайта</h2>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>От кого:</strong> ".$username."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Почта:</strong> ".$usermail."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Телефон:</strong> ".$usertel."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Сообщение:</strong> ".$usermessage."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "</body></html>";

// отправка сообщения
if(@mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
    echo "<center><img src='images/spasibo.png'></center>";
} else {
    echo "<center><img src='images/ne-tpravleno.png'></center>";
}

?>

JavaScript

$(document).ready(function() {

$('button').on('click', function() {
   $.get('http://buchid0.ho.ua/application.php', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
   });
});

    //E-mail Ajax Send
    $("#form").submit(function() { //Change
        var th = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "application.php", //Change
            data: $(this).serialize()
        }).done(function() {
            alert("Thank you!");
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Как  сделать чтоб она работала???

Comment: что именно у Вас не работает?

Comment: при нажатии на "отправить" перенаправляет на файл с php и отображается картинка с неверным адресом.  Заявка на почту не приходит, Что делать в таком случае???

Answer (score 0):

Javascript здесь точно будет лишним. Если не особо переделывать код, например, файл index.php:

```
<!--form-->
    <form id="application" action="index.php" method="POST" name="application">
        <h1>Форма заказа</h1>
         <input name="name" id="applicationName" maxlength="100" placeholder="Введите ваше имя" required />
         <input name="email" type="email" id="applicationEmail" maxlength="100" placeholder="Введите ваш E-mail" required />
         <input name="telephone" type="Tel" id="applicationTelephone" maxlength="20" placeholder="Введите ваш телефон" required />
         <input name="message" type="text" id="applicationMessage" maxlength="500" placeholder="Сообщение" required/>
         <button class="applicationButton" type="submit" form="application">Отправить</button>
      </form>



<?php 

if(empty($_POST)) die();
$sendto   = "bushido-market@ukr.net"; // почта, на которую будет приходить письмо
$username = $_POST['name'];   // сохраняем в переменную данные полученные из поля c именем
$usertel = $_POST['telephone']; // сохраняем в переменную данные полученные из поля c телефонным номером
$usermail = $_POST['email']; // сохраняем в переменную данные полученные из поля c адресом электронной почты
$usermessage = $_POST['message']; // сохраняем в переменную данные полученные из поля c адресом электронной почты

// Формирование заголовка письма
$subject  = "Новое сообщение";
$headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n";

// Формирование тела письма
$msg  = "<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'>";
$msg .= "<h2 style='font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;'>Cообщение с сайта</h2>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>От кого:</strong> ".$username."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Почта:</strong> ".$usermail."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Телефон:</strong> ".$usertel."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Сообщение:</strong> ".$usermessage."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "</body></html>";

// отправка сообщения
if(@mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
    echo "<center><img src='images/spasibo.png'></center>";
} else {
    echo "<center><img src='images/ne-tpravleno.png'></center>";
}

?>
```